# How do I get a Google Chrome style print-preview dialogue using node-webkit?

Tags: node-webkit

I'm trying to create an app in node-webkit that allows people to print stuff. I'd like Chrome's print preview dialogue to display when I issue the print command, which shouldn't be too hard given this thing is built on Webkit. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think node-webkit has inherited from Chromium to that level. It uses the browser renderer and has some functionality like OS-specific menu or dialogs, but print-preview is not a simple functionality. Check https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Features-list

Comment: I guess window.print() works.